# Qt MIME-TYPES decodification

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, mime-types, qtreeview

I am trying to use the drag & drop functionality on a `QTreeView` with an underlying `QStandardModelItem`. The default behavior of the widget is perfect for me until it gets to the drop part where I need to perform some operation. Hence, I am going to override the `dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)` method of my `TreeView` where I would like to decode the dropped mime data.

The formats of the data I find in the mime object are "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist" and "application/x-qstandarditemmodeldatalist". Does anyone know how to decode the associated data (or where to find some documentation on it) ?

Answer (score 0):

That mime type is the default type for item views. The qt already handles this when drop is made; To enable drag'n drop do:

```
itemView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
itemView->setDragEnabled(true);
itemView->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
itemView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
itemView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

To change default behavior take a look at:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views